# Why would this deep learning model performs faster inference on CPU than GPU?

Tags: performance, machine-learning, tensorflow, gpu, deep-learning

In this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.08144.pdf "[Google's Neural Machine Translation System: Bridging the Gap between Human and Machine Translation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08144)", 2016

And at page 12, in Table 1, it is listed that the decoding time for inference on their 2016 neural translation model is almost 3x faster on CPU than GPU. Their model is highly parallelized across GPUs on the depth axis.

Would anyone have any insight?

And would this also mean that generally speaking, it is better to perform the test steps of a neural network on CPU when training on GPU? And would this be true also for models trained on only 1 GPU rather than on many?

Comment: I almost posted it into the data science one but I hesitated a lot since it is about performance, hence maybe more a code issue. Thanks. Oh, and TensorFlow.org especially redirects to StackOverflow for questions about their framework (CTRL+F for Stack Overflow here) : https://www.tensorflow.org/about/
. I guess the question will stay here since I already posted it.

Comment: I thought about the data science one as well. I half-expected they might have had a machine-learning subsite. I just think your question will be more likely to be seen by serious CSci types in one of the more specialized forums.

Comment: Yeah, I expected too to find a stack exchange site about Deep Learning or at least Machine Learning, but, well.

Comment: @barry-johnson when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Yeah, exactly, I would not do that.

Comment: @Mayken, my question seems legitimate according to the links you sent me. My question sits under the theme "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" and does not fall under the the exception since it is about the TensorFlow framework: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." Moreover, my question covers "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: Moreover let me remind you that TensorFlow.org refers to StackOverflow explicitly on their website. Does my question really deserves all this madness, moderator attention, or else plain trolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used 88 CPU cores and denoted it as CPU, while only a single GPU is used. Therefore the theoretical peak performance is not that different. Next the data has to be loaded into the GPU which is an overhead, that is not needed on a CPU. The combination of those two factors make the CPU process perform better.